# Changing specific entry in nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

Suppose we are given a nested list such as the following:

```
a = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

We would like to change `1` to `'one'`. To do so, we simply do `a[0][0][0] = 'one'`.

How do I write a function to do this? In particular, I would like to define a function `foo` that takes a nested list (nesting depth can vary) and a list of indices (in the case I illustrated that would be `[0, 0, 0]`) and a replacement value (`'one'` in the example I provided) and returns the nested list with the element in the specified index replaced.

To link this back to the example I gave, the function should do the following:

```
>> foo(a, [0, 0, 0], 'one') 
[[['one', 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

Although I have worked with Python for some time, this seems surprisingly not straightforward.

Comment: Do you know these indexes beforehand ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce` with `operator.getitem` for this:

```
a = [[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]]

from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

def foo(L, idx, var):
    reduce(getitem, idx[:-1], L)[idx[-1]] = var

foo(a, [0,0,0], 'one') 

print(a)

[[['one', 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```

Comment: These are two libraries I definitely need to get familiar with! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you this simple function `foo()`, without any imported package:

```
def foo(a, b, value):
    c = a
    for i in b[:-1]:
        c = c[i]
    c[b[-1]] = value

a = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
foo(a, [0, 0, 0], 'one') 

print(a)
# [[['one', 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]

a = [[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]]
foo(a, [0, 0, 0, 1], 'two') 

print(a)
# [[[[1, 'one'], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]]
```

I may also suggest you a recursive function as follows:

```
def foo(a, b, value):
    if len(b) == 1:
        a[b[0]] = value
    else:
        foo(a[b[0]], b[1:], value)
```